# Scanner.nextLine() error: salta una linea

Tags: java, scanner

Me encuentro ocupando Java y debo de ingresar unos datos por teclado, para ello uso `Scanner` con el método `.nextLine()`, el problema es que el programa simplemente se salta uno de los `.nextLine()` no dejando que ingrese el "nombre" pero si me deja ingresar "pass"

---

Código que uso para ingresar datos (la definición de nombre y pass están mas arriba como: `String nombre, pass;`)

```
System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ");
nombre = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese una contrasenia: ");
pass = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("nombre de usuario: " + nombre);
System.out.println("contrasenia:" + pass);
```

---

Y la salida es esta:

```
elija la opcion que desee: 
1) Logear
2) Registrar
3) Salir
2
Ingrese su nombre de usuario: 
Ingrese una contrasenia: 
Aldo
nombre de usuario
contrasenia:Aldo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: En el código que tienes no debe haber problema, pero si en las lineas anteriores a este donde se usa sc, agrega ese código.

Comment: Exactamente, era la parte de capturar la opcion, muchas gracias de igual forma!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema seguramente sucede al llamar  `sc.nextInt()` para elegir una opción y posteriormente tratar de obtener el usuario.

El problema sucede al llamar [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) o [nextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) ya que estos métodos a diferencia de [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) no leen el caracter de nueva linea al dar clic en la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> para ingresar la información.

Para solucionar este problema usa después de `sc.nextInt()` o `sc.nextDouble()` un `sc.nextLine()` y posteriormente obtén el nombre del usuario :

```
System.out.println("elija la opcion que desee: ");
...
...   
int opcion    = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); //*Agrega esto para consumir la nueva linea!

System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ");    
nombre = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese una contrasenia: ");
pass = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: WOOOW! muchas gracias! y eso que no puse es porcion de codigo ajajaj

Comment: Suponía que usabas nextInt() para obtener la opción ;-) , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema puedes utilizar `Integer.parseInt()` o `Double.parseDouble()` dependiendo del tipo de dato, para evitar lo que esta sucediendo. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("elija la opcion que desee: ");
int opcion = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ");    
nombre = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese una contrasenia: ");
pass = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/política-temporal-chatgpt-está-prohibido)