# nextLine() error: salta una linea

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa por consola donde se almacenan datos varios de estudiantes en Java, pero me tope con este problema

```
option = input.nextByte();
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar estudiante");
                    System.out.println("Ingresar nombres:");
                    name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar apellidos:");
                    lastName = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar fecha de nacimiento (YYYY-MM-DD):");
                    birthday = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar correo institucional:");
                    institutionalMail = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar correo personal:");
                    mail = input.next();
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Ingresar número de celular:");
                        cell = input.nextLong();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        cell = 0;
                    }
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Ingresar número fijo:");
                        phone = input.nextLong();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        phone = 0;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Ingresar programa:");
                    schedule = input.next();
                    
                    user.createStudient(name, lastName, institutionalMail, mail, schedule, birthday, cell, phone);
                    break;}
```

Como se dan cuenta en el codigo hay dos nextLine seguidos, he intentado de las maneras que me disponen la web de vaciar el buffer y el metodo skip, pero obviamente no es logico, en la primera solución el valor no se almacena es decir queda vacio y el segundo como no pasa del nextLine() esta tomando n veces el mismo valor y si dejamos el codigo tal cual se salta el primero.
Y pues no encontrado la solución agradeceria que me ayudaran con este problema

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el código con el que intentas usar los objetos que creas con `nextLine()`?

Comment: Ya lo adjunte en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirando una pregunta similar, encontre el error que tenia [Scanner.nextLine() error: salta una linea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229152/scanner-nextline-error-salta-una-linea?rq=1)
Al mirar el codigo me falto poner que estoy haciendo una nextByte() antes de crear el estudiante, entonces cuando yo pongo la opción queda de esta manera "2\n" y se saltaba el nextLine().
La solucion seria esta

```
option = input.nextByte();
            input.nextLine();
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Ingresar estudiante");
                    System.out.println("Ingresar nombres:");
                    name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar apellidos:");
                    lastName = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar fecha de nacimiento (YYYY-MM-DD):");
                    birthday = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar correo institucional:");
                    institutionalMail = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Ingresar correo personal:");
                    mail = input.next();
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Ingresar número de celular:");
                        cell = input.nextLong();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        cell = 0;
                    }
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Ingresar número fijo:");
                        phone = input.nextLong();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        phone = 0;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Ingresar programa:");
                    schedule = input.next();
                    
                    user.createStudient(name, lastName, institutionalMail, mail, schedule, birthday, cell, phone);
                    break;
```

Agragando un nextLine(), despues del nextByte()
Muchas gracias por la molestias

Comment: Dale al check para aceptar tu respuesta y cerrar así la pregunta

Comment: Me dice que puedo aceptarla en dos días